# Deleting a row in a table cause program to crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delete-row

Stripped my code down to the bare basics, and when I press the delete button, the app crashes. Any ideas?

Here is the delete code. As I say, bare basics.

```
  - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


     if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
                //remove the deleted object from your data source.
                //If your data source is an NSMutableArray, do this




   [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];


            }


    }
```

Comment: What's the crash error? You're deleting the row from your table view, but you're not deleting the item from your data source.

Comment: Deleting the object from datasource did the job. Thanks mate!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle: (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle==UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    { 
        [dataArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }

    [tableView reloadData];
}
```

Hope it helps.